# Slow loading of images on IIS 6, Windows Server 2003

Tags: image, iis-6, performance, loading

I have a Windows Server 2003 64-Bit VPS, and I'm experiencing a problem with pages, or rather more specifically images loading slow for all of the websites that are hosted on it.

I have a shared hosting account with a particular company and also the VPS, and an identical site loads slower on the VPS.

Initially I thought it was a coding problem on one particular site, but this is not the issue. Most of the sites are built using ASP, but the problem also occurs on a HTML only website with minimal content.

The HTML seems to load ok albeit slower than the shared hosting (which obviously shouldnt be the case), and then the images slowly appear on the page one by one.  Refreshing the page causes the images to load slowly again, rather than a more or less instant refresh for sites on the shared hosting.

I've spent the last week reading forum post after forum post and I cant seem to find any help.

Previous to this, I was using the exact same VPS albeit in 32-bit, and the problem didnt occur. I have installed the same software on the VPS as on the old 32-bit server. (SQL Server 2005 Express, ISAPI Rewrite, MailEnable Professional).

Does anyone have any ideas why this could be happening?

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: Wouldn't this belong to serverfault.com or superuser.com, doesn't seems dev-related.

Comment: I wasnt aware of these sites, I'll check them out in future - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say. How much RAM does your VPS have?

What is the VM hosting solution? If it is a Virtual Server then it might be this issue:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888750

In IIS - are images handled by .Net?

If you disable ISAPI Rewrite - is performance still slow?

Do you store/extract images from the SQL database?

Comment: I just tried disabling ISAPI Rewrite and the problem went away! Thanks. This is strange because I had the same filter installed on the previous system without any problem.

I will now take this up with Helicon.

Thanks.

Chris.

Comment: Glad that you found the culprit. We considered Helicon's ISAPI rewrite for one of our projects. I works fine for small loads but we definitely saw a bottleneck as part of stress tests. It was related to the number of simultaneous requests this filter can handle and from memory it was something around 10 requests where we were hitting the limit.